# how to use function eval in telerik:RadTicker?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

this is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptsalamat" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadTicker RegisterWithScriptManager="true" AutoStart="true" runat="server"
            ID="Radticker1" Loop="true">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadTickerItem> 
                             <%#Eval("txtTitle") %> 
                </telerik:RadTickerItem>
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadTicker>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

i cannot use   <%#Eval("txtTitle") %> What should I do for it?

Comment: <asp:Repeater> <ItemTemplate>
                          <telerik:RadTickerItem   >

                                 <%#Eval("txtTitle") %> 
                          </telerik:RadTickerItem> </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:Repeater> hoe to use asp:Repeater

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptsalamat" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadTicker RegisterWithScriptManager="true" AutoStart="true" runat="server"
                ID="Radticker1" Loop="true">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadTickerItem Text='<%#Eval("txtTitle") %>'> 
                    </telerik:RadTickerItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadTicker>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```